# Excel 2016: How to find out the row number of a max value?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'd like to find out the row number of the max value. Give example below:

```
100
101
102
103
104
105
=MAX(C3:C8)
105
```

I need to know the ROW number of the MAX value which is 105 here. If I place 100 at A1 then my desired output should be **6**.

Excel doesn't allow me to use:

```
    =ROW(MAX(A1:A6))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the max number by using the `=MAX()` as you suggested, next you can use the `MATCH()` formula to find the row where the max value is found. Try something like this:

`=MATCH(MAX(A:A);A:A)`

Comment: What with to row's with same maximum value?

Answer (score 2):

If you can, use a helper column on the right

Just do `=ROW()` to the right, you can simply `=VLOOKUP(MAX(A1:A6),A1:B6,2,FALSE)` and it will return the row.

Remember that if you do this and there are duplicates of the Max value, it will only return the row of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the (quite old) unanswered question posed by M. Siwik, here's how you can get all the rows pertaining to the maximum value.

[image: 1]

The first cell (B1) indicates the first row that matches the minimum value of the selected range.The "0" in the match function is important because it allows excel to find the first matching value without the range being ordered, which would be necessary if the value is -1, 1 or omitted.

[image]

The subsequent cells indicate the next row that matches the minimum value. Once they start repeating, you found the last cell containing the maximum, so the results on B4 and B5, in this example, are unnecessary. If the last value in the data range is NOT a maximum, the formula returns N/A.

[image]